# Working on clear cache App getting Error in an Asynctask method

Tags: java, android, file, android-asynctask

I am working on file scanner App and clear cache it is crash on activity . my application has clear cache like boost application, unstall apk from app Ram boost etc ........

```
 private void travelPath(File root, int level) {
    if (root == null || !root.exists() || level > SCAN_LEVEL) {
        return;
    }

    File[] lists = root.listFiles();
    for (File file : lists) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String name = file.getName();
            JunkInfo info = null;
            if (name.endsWith(".apk")) {
                info = new JunkInfo();
                info.mSize = file.length();
                info.name = name;
                info.mPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                info.mIsChild = false;
                info.mIsVisible = true;
                mApkInfo.mChildren.add(info);
                mApkInfo.mSize += info.mSize;
            } else if (name.endsWith(".log")) {
                info = new JunkInfo();
                info.mSize = file.length();
                info.name = name;
                info.mPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                info.mIsChild = false;
                info.mIsVisible = true;
                mLogInfo.mChildren.add(info);
                mLogInfo.mSize += info.mSize;
            } else if (name.endsWith(".tmp") || name.endsWith(".temp")) {
                info = new JunkInfo();
                info.mSize = file.length();
                info.name = name;
                info.mPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                info.mIsChild = false;
                info.mIsVisible = true;
                mTmpInfo.mChildren.add(info);
                mTmpInfo.mSize += info.mSize;
            }

            if (info != null) {
                mCallback.onProgress(info);
            }
        } else {
            if (level < SCAN_LEVEL) {
                travelPath(file, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and LogCat error is :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.travelPath(OverallScanTask.java:35)
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.doInBackground(OverallScanTask.java:85)
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.doInBackground(OverallScanTask.java:15)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.travelPath(OverallScanTask.java:35)
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.doInBackground(OverallScanTask.java:85)
    at com.example.dell.testnew.custom.OverallScanTask.doInBackground(OverallScanTask.java:15)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
```

getting error here  for loop for a file scanner

Thank you in Advance for help i will appreciate your answer

Comment: I believe your `root.listFiles()` returned null, which means the `root` was not a directory.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: in marshmallow it is working

Comment: Maybe it has a different directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Files.listFiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listFiles()) can return null if it is not a directory:

> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

If you do not expect it to be null, then you should probably revisit your code logic and find a workaround, otherwise you can easily handle it with a null check.